# Why was Raymond Reddington's immunity agreement not mentioned before the court case?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-blacklist

We see in S6E3 ["The Pharmacist"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJMT8c_rr-s) that Red is forced to go through the (relatively short) process of defending himself despite being a confidential informant of the federal government.

Assistant Director Cooper is in the courtroom whilst this is going on, and continues to allow it until being directly called up by the judge herself.

What possible reason would they have to *not* mention this beforehand? Did they *want* Red to get charged? Was he just <s>fucking</s> messing with Red to see how well he could self-represent?

I'm not a lawyer by any stretch of the imagination, but I feel as though something like this should've been dealt with before it even got to the courtroom.

Is there a canonical reason this happened - or is it just an oversight to make him look like a bit of a badass?

Comment: Hi, welcome to movies&TV, maybe you could edit your question so there is only one question ?

Comment: I only vaguely remember this episode, but wasn't it because the Govt didn't want it known that they had been working with "The World's Most Wanted Man"(TM) rather than jailing him?

Comment: @Darren That's a good point. But wouldn't it be a bit strange if there was a court case for the most wanted man in the world just being thrown out? :o